# No permission to download my own file in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can see I have the all the checkboxes checked in S3 panel with me as the Grantee.

But when I try access the URL or downloading the file, it says access is denied.

I don't want to change permission to everyone.

Why can't I download my own file?

Comment: Let's clarify: When you select a file in the S3 console, then choose Actions > Download, what happens next, exactly?

Comment: @Jedi, @Michael, I'm in AWS console. Was trying to download via the `https` link in properties tab of the file. But I realised I can download it fine via the `Actions > Download` menu. That works for me. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @resting do you notice what's different in the request generated by Actions > Download? :-)

Comment: @Jedi, didn't bother, but since you asked, ya, I see a very very long signature :)